# How can I make my character work in my 2d top down game?

Tags: unity, c#, 2d

I have two sprite sheets and they have to work together. I don't know how to make frames animation and everything. If you could explain it to me, it would help me so much. I am using unity c++ or c# . I am a total beginner so I don’t know how to cut the sprites because the sprite is a tenplate for players to upload their character . First I need to be able to walk in 4 directions and then to be able to animate my characer so it can hold weapons and the character is supposed to be able to swim and to sit also! I really need help!

Here are the templates:

[image: body]

[image: head]

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what your tried so far and what problems you encountered?

Comment: Well I tried finding a code online to do it or an add-ons I didn't find it. But I know some games work with two templates and I have no idea how they did I need help to understand how to code that. I am a total 0 in coding.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to [gamedev.se]! I have edited your post and removed several parts that called for downvotes. Keep in mind that by uploading to StackExchange's imgur account, you agree that your images are now under the license described [here](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/). Also, keep in mind that even if you ask users not to steel, that doesn't prevent anything in this big wild Internet world, so no need to mention it.

Comment: that still doesn't help me get my codes..

Comment: Can you please edit your post to explain in detail what you want to accomplish with these images? There are a lot of steps between a spritesheet and a playable character, so we need to narrow down what's the first step in that journey you need help with. Is it safe to assume you've successfully imported the images into Unity as sprites, sliced them into their individual parts, and assembled your character's idle pose in the scene view? If so, it sounds like what you need next would be either setting up animations or facing states. If not, tell us where you're stuck.

Answer (score -1):

For Platformers check out https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dwcT-Dch0bA&t=761s or for top down try https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pk3GCgaNVTY&list=PLiyfvmtjWC_X6e0EYLPczO9tNCkm2dzkm You will need to make your question more specific if you want more than just a pointer to good tutorials :D

Comment: Currently this is a link-only answer, something we try to avoid here since we've had ongoing problems with link rot. If the URL ever changes or becomes unavailable, there's nothing in this answer to help a future user figure out what strategies you were recommending. If you edit your answer so that the body contains at least a rough summary of the key points you hope a user will learn from those links, then it becomes more robust, more searchable/accessible, and easier to scan when evaluating which answers to try or upvote.